# How to obtain individual numbers from Rectangle intersection

Tags: java, awt

I am using the `java.awt.Rectangle` class and the intersection method.

```
Rectangle rect1 = new Rectangle(1, 2, 3, 4);
Rectangle rect2 = new Rectangle(2, 3, 4, 5);
Rectangle intersection = rect1.intersection(rect2);
System.out.println(intersection);
```

The output is:

```
 java.awt.Rectangle[x=2,y=3,width=2,height=3]
```

How do I get each individual number? Such as assign the answers to variables `x = hello` or `width = hi`. I want to format the output to be:

```
Intersection: (2.0, 3.0, 2.0, 3.0)
```

Comment: Did you check the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/Rectangle.html)?

Comment: I got the answer by playing around..

it's `intersection.width`

but, how do you convert so `Rectangle` accepts float. Documentation said `Rectangle(int, int, int, int)`.

Comment: Yeah did you even try to read the documentation? There is a getX, getY, getWidth and getHeight methods.

Answer (score 0):

Is this only about the fomatting? You can write a simple function that would take a Rectangle object and return your desired string, i.e:

```
public String formatRectangleOutput(Rectangle rectangle) {
    String base = "Intersection (%.2f, %.2f, %.2f, %.2f)";
    return String.format(base, rectangle.getX(), rectangle.getY(), rectangle.getHeight(), rectangle.getWidth());
}
```

then you could call it like:

```
        System.out.println(formatRectangleOutput(intersection));
```

To get each individual number you just need so-called `getters` which are `rectangle.getX()` or `rectangle.getY()`

Comment: Thank you! But is there a way to make 'Rectangle' accept fractional numbers? I know their default is to accept int but I need my inputs to be float. I get this error when I try to use the variables (in float) to Rectangle class:
`incompatible types: possible lossy conversion from float to int`

Comment: If I am not mistaken those ints represent pixels. What is the point to draw something in a half of a pixel?

Comment: Sorry, this is homework. I will just turn them to ints and hopefully my professor doesn't check my codes. Thank you!